# Python query to find records with more than one alpha character in a field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, query

Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.  I have a field in a table of several thousand records.  The field is made up of alphanumeric characters.  I'd like to perform two queries using python on this field:

1. Identify the records in this field that contain more than one alpha character
2. Identify the records in this field that end with more than one alpha character

Comment: You could try taking the string, break it up into each individual character *stringName*[*index*] and run it against a regular expression.  You can use that and count the instances and use arcpy.UpdateCursor to assign that value to a new field.  You can do the same idea except use negatives to get the end characters.  Ie. -1, -2 to count back the last two characters in the string.

Comment: How do you want the results outputted? What have you tried?

Comment: Python Regular Expressions:https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Comment: I want the output to be a selection within the table.  Have not tried anything yet but working on it now.

Comment: Also forgot.. you would need to set up a arcpy.SearchCursor first to parse through records.  Basic process I would take.. Set up a Search Cursor --> Loop through Records and on each iteration --> grab field information --> loop through string characters of that field -- > run each character against a Regex --> update a count field when done --> then take that field string again and check the last two characters against a Regex --> update a flag field for last two alphas --> the script moves to next record. Then select based on attributes after to get your selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below function returns the number of alpha characters in a string:

```
def NumAlhpa(fieldName):
   return len([s for s in fieldName if not s.isdigit()])
```

you can easily integrate this into the Field calculator:

```
YourField = NumAlpha( !yourColumnName! )
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer part 1 more directly, you can modify Matej's Field Calculator function to return a boolean indicating whether each record contains more than one alpha character:

```
def has_multi_alpha(fieldName):
    num_alpha = len([s for s in fieldName if not s.isdigit()])
    if num_alpha > 1:
        return True  # or 1
    else:
        return False  # or 0
```

To answer part two, you can use the following Field Calculator function, which will check the last two characters (since any others are irrelevant):

```
def ends_with_two_alpha(fieldName):
    last2 = fieldName[-2:]
    num_alpha = len([s for s in last2 if not s.isdigit()])
    if num_alpha == 2:
        return True  # or 1
    else:
        return False  # or 0
```

Comment: nmpeterson, thanks! Between yours and Matej's response, I have exactly what I need :)